# How to record the count of a TaskList

Tags: batch-file

I have a process called "Ulti.exe". Due to my project requirements I have more than one copy of it running at any one time. If the number of copies of "Ulti.exe" drop below 3, I need to kill all the processes and restart them again.

How can I save the TaskList count into a variable? Currently, the following command:

```
TaskList | FIND /C "Ulti.exe"
```

if typed into cmd.exe returns me the number of "Ulti.exe" processes accurately. How can I incorporate this into a .bat file so I can use this number as a variable?

Comment: Either write the result to a file and read it back in with `Set /P` or put your command `IN`side `For /F` parentheses and capture the output using `Do Set`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the output of a command with a `for /f` loop:

```
for /f %%a in ('TaskList ^| FIND /I /C "Ulti.exe"') do set count=%%a
echo %count%
```

Answer (score 0):

While counting you can as well gather the PIDs to ease killing them if needed

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\11\02\SO_53115422.cmd
@Echo off & SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

Set "Prog=Ulti.exe"
::Set "Prog=firefox.exe"

Set "Count="
Set "PIDs="

for /f "tokens=2" %%A in (
    'TaskList /FI "IMAGENAME eq %Prog%" ^| Findstr /i "%Prog%"'
) do (
    Set /A Count+=1
    Set PIDs=!PIDs! /PID %%A
)

If defined Count (
    If !Count! lss 3 (
         echo taskkill %PIDs%
         echo restart %Prog%
    ) else (
        echo %Prog% running %Count% times [%PIDs%]
    )
) else (
    Echo %Prog% not running
    Echo start %Prog%
)
```

Sample output:

```
> SO_53115422
Ulti.exe running 5 times [ /PID 3664 /PID 10332 /PID 3544 /PID 8996 /PID 11192]

> SO_53115422
Ulti.exe not running
start Ulti.exe

> SO_53115422
taskkill  /PID 8056 /PID 2704
restart Ulti.exe
```

The taskkill command is only echoed while testing